# Posting review and display review on the same page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am building an app that allows users view a book, post a review of the book on the same page and see their reviews when successfully posted. My goal is to have everything happen on the same page.

I am using Laravel 5.7 and this is what my code looks like currently

web.php

```
Route::post('books/{book}', 'RatingController@store');
```

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
}
```

view

```
<form action="/books/{{$book->id}}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">

    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, I don't see the data dumped but I remain on the same page and the url looks like this instead `http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/1?_token=gAkb9P6ryh2vVs4nj0db4gggBzqZPzUg0fQp3fCC&username=Fomsky&comment=awesome+reading`

This is not the intended behavior I want, I want to use the `request` data inside my controller hence the reason why i am dumping it first.

What is the proper way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

> ******* OPTION 1 ********

**Route**

```
Route::resource('books', 'RatingController');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('books.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{ $book->id}}">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
</form>
```

> ******* OPTION 2 ********

**Route**

```
Route::post('books/store', 'RatingController')->name('books_store');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('books_store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{ $book->id}}">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="3"></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
</form>
```